# Removing certain characters in a string

Tags: java, replace

I want to remove the equal sign in the string below.

```
String str = "[=Ind(\"Blr-ind\",\"Company\")]";
```

Comment: Look over http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html, there must be some method there that can help you.

Comment: why don't you replace that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `String.replaceFirst()` on the string:

```
String input = "[=Ind(\"Blr-ind\",\"Company\")]";
input = input.replaceFirst("=", "");

System.out.println(input);
```

**Output:**

```
[Ind("Blr-ind","Company")]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also use `String.replaceAll()` to replace all occurrences by any other String

```
String input = "[=Ind(\"Blr-ind\",\"Company\")]";
input = input.replaceAll("=", "");

System.out.println(input);
```

Answer (score 1):

just use the replace method :

```
String s = "[=Ind(\"Blr-ind\",\"C=ompany\")]";

s = s.replace("=", "");
```